# Библиотека для отображения сообщений чата под Android

Tags: android, chat

Нужна библиотека для отображения сообщений чата.
Что-то похожее на [этой](http://www.jessesquires.com/JSQMessagesViewController/), но она только для `iOS`.

Comment: [Раз](https://github.com/himanshu-soni/ChatMessageView), [два](https://github.com/devcenter-square/android-chat-ui) и еще можно найти кучу.

Comment: Вот еще статья: https://www.quora.com/I-want-develop-a-chatting-app-in-android-What-is-best-library-or-sdk-to-handle-huge-number-of-users

Comment: Но пока подходящего ничего не вижу (Чтобы отображало Сообщения, картинки, видео, места (карты))

Comment: Чтобы все отображало - WebView используйте для показа сообщений. Вы и правда думаете, что кто-то специально для вас сделал уже библиотеку? Зачем тогда вообще ваши услуги?

Comment: Я не думаю, я уверен, что она уже есть. Просто нужно выбрать подходящую.

Comment: @Shwarz Andrei что непонятного в моем вопросе? Есть библиотека для отображения сообщений чата под iOS - мой вопрос - какие есть аналоги под Андроид. Что нужно уточнить?

Comment: @post_zeew ссылка "два" - не рабочая... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полностью OpenSource 100% customizable UI kit:
https://atlas.layer.com/android